# Uploading an image to imgur using the imgur npm package

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, imgur

I'm using SvelteKit and Typescript for a project, and I want to upload photos to Imgur using the Imgur API using [the imgur npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur). However, no matter what I do, I get an error response: `{ data: 'response was empty', status: 500, success: false }`.

Here is what I have (this is in a `page.server.ts` file, the `upload` action is triggered when the form containing the image is submitted.

```
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { ImgurClient } from 'imgur';
import { IMGUR_CLIENT_ID, IMGUR_CLIENT_SECRET } from '$env/static/private';

export const actions = {
    async upload({ request }) {
        const formData = await request.formData();

        const img = formData.get('image');
        if (!img || !(img instanceof Object) || !img.name) return fail(400);

        const buffer = Buffer.from(await img.arrayBuffer());
        const base64 = buffer.toString('base64');

        // I have validated that the base64 string produced here is correct

        const imgur = new ImgurClient({
            clientId: IMGUR_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: IMGUR_CLIENT_SECRET
        });

        const response = await imgur.upload({
            image: base64,
            type: 'base64'
        });

        console.log(response);
        
        // the response looks like this:
        // { data: 'response was empty', status: 500, success: false }
    }
};
```

I have registered my application with imgur and have recieved a client ID and client secret, which I'm passing into `ImgurClient`. What am I doing wrong?